# Is there a way to have two images in a VStack and have the images resized and scaledToFill? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

I have two images in a VStack and both images being resizable. One of the image is set to fill with clipped.

```
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    Image(uiImage: project.image!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "ic_add_project")!)
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "corner_pages_72pt")!)
            .resizable()
    }
}
```

I have almost the result I wanted by removing `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` but the top image get stretch and distorted.

[image: Stretch]

How can I set two images one on top of each other with the same size and have the image scaledToFill so it doesn't get stretch? I can't use fixed frame size, I'm hoping to distribute the images evenly between the stacks.

[image: Broken]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put them into overlay of color. Color fills available space, so two colors fill space equally, and images in overlay should be sized as specified not affecting each other.

```
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    Color.clear.overlay(
       Image(uiImage: project.image!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    )
    Color.clear.overlay(
      ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "ic_add_project")!)
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "corner_pages_72pt")!)
            .resizable()
    })
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I only needed the Color overlay for the top one, which is the one with fill.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
VStack(spacing: 8) {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
        
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
        }
    }
```